# Ascending ID along split line

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, line

I have a line which I intersected with a polygon layer in order to split the line along the polygon borders and add the polygons' attributes to the lines. Further processing of this data happens in Excel - but before this I need to add an ascending ID along the line for easier orientation.

I am able to add the current `$ID` of the lines, but it is not sorted/ascending.
[image]

How can I add an ascending ID which follows the line direction?

Using QGIS 3.10

Comment: Which QGIS version?

Comment: QGIS 3.10 @StuSmith

Comment: The original line is only one?

Comment: Yes, I start out with one single, continuous line - and a continuous set of polygons which cover all of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the following expression in the Field Calculator

```
array_find(
    array_sort(
        array_agg( 
            line_locate_point(  
            aggregate('line','collect',$geometry),  line_interpolate_point( $geometry,0.001)))),  
    line_locate_point(  
    aggregate('line','collect',$geometry), line_interpolate_point( $geometry,0.001))
)+1
```

The expression will calculate the order of the segmented lines (`lines` in the example) according to the distance of the lines from the starting point of your original line (`line` in the example).
The lines location is calculated in a point located close to the start_point and not in the start_point to avoid possible concomitances.

An example in the image

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I still struggle with the `aggregate` function.