# How does the expression look like to sort route segments of multiple routes using start and end coordinates of segments in qgis?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, coordinates, expression, sorting

I do have a line layer containing multiple route segments. Having a route_id (string type; for example A101-1, B207, ...) as attribute for each segments tells me to which route the segment belongs. However, I do not have a segment_id. This segment_id's should be ordered from start to end of the route, starting for each route with 001, 002, 003, and so on (in the end, route_id and segment_id will be combined, e.g. A101-1_001, A101-1_002). I'd like to use the start and end coordinates of the segment for the sorting. For this, I have two attributes called coords_start (string type) and coords_end (string type) containing x and y coordinates.

In short: I need a function, grouped by route_id, which does something like that:

1. searches the coords_start which are not in coords_end -> segment_id = 001
2. having this coords_start looking if the coords_end of that feature are inside of the coords_start of another feature -> segment_id = 002
3. having this coords_start looking if the coords_end of that feature are inside of the coords_start of another feature -> segment_id = 003
4. and so on until it can't find coords_end inside coords_start of another feature anymore

Does someone has an idea how this expression should look? I prefer using field calculator rather than python...

Comment: If you're asking how to create an ascending ID along a line, have a look: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367584/ascending-id-along-split-line

Comment: I do - in a way. I've had a look at that example, trying with only one selected route in my layer. Though it gave me strange numbers (177, 242, 243, 312, ...). It's also not the fid or something... I'm also not sure if I really understand what the expression is doing..

Comment: AH, found it, it's the index.. but because I do have a lot of routes for which the number should always start with 001 for the first segment it does not work..

Comment: I guess you'd have to add something which groups the segments by the routes they belong to. I suggest you provide example data.

Comment: yes, that's what I guess as well. but I also need a layer containing the routes without segments, is that correct? cause I don't have that.. I'm not sure if that's really the solution for my problem...